# IOS Berkeley DB development issue

Tags: ios, berkeley-db

Hi i followed below procedure for generating libdb-cxx-6.1.a library.

https://ankitthakur.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/build-scripts-for-berkely-db-static-libraries-with-ios-development/

But after importing libdb-cxx-6.1.a and include files in xcode 5.1 i am seeing below exception

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/rajaramesh/build7forios/lib/libdb_cxx-6.1.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

I changed mac o  type to static library then i am  choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device. I done build for armv7 only not i386 and armv7s architecture. I am implemeting ios application using cordova. Did i miss any thing. Please advise me.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above problem resolved using following steps.

1) Build architecture for i386 architecture.
2) make realclean
3) Build architecture for armv7, architecture.
4) Got two lib_cxx-6.1.dylib for i386 and armv7.

5) Using lipo  create command generated universal build.

6) imported in to xcode framework.

Thanks.